# Prove that $E$ (defined in the text body) is a vector subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

For some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let A $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and let $y_0 \in  \text{range}(A)$.
Prove that $E = \{3ty_0 : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by checking the subspace criteria.

Now, I know the subspace criteria for a subspace $V$:

1. $0 \in V$
2. $v,w \in V \rightarrow v+w \in V$
3. $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,       $\ \lambda \cdot v \in V$

I tried reasoning that we can assume w.l.o.g that A represents a linear transformation and by this logic then of course $0 \in \text{range}(A)$, which means $0 \in E$, and the rest follows too. But I am pretty sure that this is completely wrong.

Comment: Try calculating all the subspace criteria by hand. Note that $y_0$ is arbitrary but fixed for an E. As such you can't "choose" your $y_0$ as in your argumentation on why $0 \in E$. So let $y_0 \in range(A)$ be arbitrary and then work with this $y_0$ and $E_{y_0}$.
For example for $t = 0$ what Element in $E$ do you get and so on?
And if you take arbitrary Elements in $E$ how can you write them w.l.o.g.?

Comment: So I have misunderstood that $y_0$ is the variable? 
So if t is the variable I then get: 1. t=0, $3*0*y_0 = 0 \rightarrow 0 \in E $.  
2. $t_1$ , $t_2$ $\rightarrow 3*t_1*y_0 + 3*t_1*y_0 = 3*(t_1 + t_2) * y_0 $

Is that correct? Sorry for the mess, I haven't quite figured out how LaTex works..

Comment: Basically that's correct yes. 
It depens what you mean with $y_0$ to be "the variable". You could also rewrite the statement you want to prove as $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \forall A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \forall y_0 \in range(A):$ and then follow with the statement that's to be shown .... In that case one could permute the $\forall$'s and it'd be the same statement

Comment: Your criterion 3 is not correctly stated: you are missing the hypothesis that $v\in V$.

Comment: The problem can be simplified a lot. For all $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a matrix $A$ such that $y_0 \in \operatorname{range}(A)$. And $3t y_0 = t(3y_0)$ for all $t$. So the problem is really just about the set $E$ of all scalar multiples of a single vector.